# How to replace line-breaks with spaces in a file?

Tags: python, file

I am reading a file like this:

```
path = '/home/onur/Deep3dPortrait/examples/'
detections = os.listdir(path + 'detections/')
landmarks = os.listdir(path + 'landmarks/')

for file in detections:
    with open(path + 'detections/' + file, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

This is the output:

```
128.0 96.0
191.0 96.0
182.0 136.0
138.0 181.0
186.0 180.0
```

How can I replace the linebreaks with spaces in every single such file? I want the file to look like this:

```
128.0 96.0 191.0 96.0 182.0 136.0 138.0 181.0 186.0 180.0
```

I know I can use `str.replace('\n', ' ')` but how can I actually edit the contents of the file line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `replace`, but you need to `f.write` after:

```py
# Open and over-write (r+)
with open("file.txt", 'r+') as f:
    x = f.read()
    x = x.replace("\n", " ")
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(x)
```

Comment: `f.write(x)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Comment: Did you use `"r+"`?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't edit a file in-place: you read it and write elsewhere. You can then replace the input file with the output once you've succeeded.

```
with open('input.txt', 'rt') as fi, open('output.txt', 'wt') as fo:
    for line in fi:
        fo.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
# optionally move output.txt to input.txt afterward
```

That being said, for small files and toy examples, you can read in the whole thing and then write it back under the same name:

```
with open('input.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('input.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(data.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using regex:

```py
import re
path = '/home/onur/Deep3dPortrait/examples/'
detections = os.listdir(path + 'detections/')
landmarks = os.listdir(path + 'landmarks/')

for file in detections:
    with open(path + 'detections/' + file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(re.sub("\n", " ", f.read()))
```

Comment: Only prints the changes. The files remain as they are..

Comment: @oo92 Use `w` instead of `r` and write the output into the file. You can gain insight into the process by looking at the edited version of my answer.

Comment: `f.wrtie` -> `f.write`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Thank you for the note, Freddy. I write the code in the edit mode:)

Comment: No worries man 